# Existential vs existing

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, comparisons

https://wikidiff.com/existential/existent tells us the differences between existential and existing.

Could you give me situations/examples

- where they are exchangeable,
- where only one is suitable while the other isn't?

For example, I heard that

> Bernie Sanders agrees somehow that he is viewed as an existential threat by Democratic establishment. (In contrast, Elizabeth Warren recently showed to Democratic establishment that she is a team player).

from recent interview on Bernie by The Hills in Kentucky, and immediately thought I would have used "existing threat" due to my limited vocabulary.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please assist me with the actual difference the two words? I'm very confused.

Comment: If he is an existential threat to the democratic establishment then he threatens their existence. If he is an existing threat, then he is a threat that exists now; we don't know how serious the threat is or whether or not it is existential.

Comment: @SConroy - Thanks a bunch for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/existential

Comment: The wikidiff linked actually shows the difference between "existential" and **"existent"**, not "existing". Personally, it seems to me the meaning, as in the popular usage, of "existential" is currently in flux, as people are using it as interchangeable with "existing". (And frankly, I personally, find this trend very grating and annoying.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meanings of the two words are different, they cannot be switched without changing the meaning of the statement.

- Existential relates to existence itself. An existential threat is something that threatens the existence of something. As [S Conroy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509743/existential-vs-existing/509745#comment1235900_509743) points out:

  > If he is an existential threat to the democratic [sic] establishment then he threatens [the establishment's] existence.

  *Note: I've retained the capitalization of the quoted comment, but 'Democratic' should be capitalized based on how it is used in the question. "**D**emocratic" refers to the political party. Whereas "**d**emocratic" refers to the governance system.*
- Existing describes something that exists. An existing threat is a threat that exists, as opposed to one that doesn't, like an imaginary one. As [S Conroy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509743/existential-vs-existing/509745#comment1235900_509743) explains:

  > If he is an existing threat, then he is a threat that exists now; we don't know how serious the threat is or whether or not it is existential.

Comment: Not the democratic establishment (more or less the constitution or its embodiment) but the Democratic establishment.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I retained the capitalization of the comment I quote.  But from the question, 'Democratic' should be capitalized. I've added a statement to clarify.

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry, that's about as clear as mud. I agree there is a difference, but I'm not satisfied the this has clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

Twenty-first century balderdash! Existing is the proper usage when speaking of some political group, thought, or movement that one want's to designate as being present or being an influencer of thoughts or outcomes. Existential is best left to the world of academic philosophy. Misuse and bastardization of the English lexicon is certainly existent. I think that, in this case, Sartre, Camus and others would agree that the misuse of our language is an ever present and existing threat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It has become increasingly common for the media to use *"existential"* when they mean *"existing"*, or *"current"*, as though they were interchangeable. Based on my education and experience, I would take *"existential"* to have a philosophical, non-concrete connotation, whereas *"existing"* is certainly concrete. (*"Existential"*, one will note, is not equivalent to *"realism"*.) I would use *"existential"* to refer to a philosophical, theoretical examination of real, empirical life, rather than concrete instances of that same real, empirical life. However, the times - may be a'changing.

This current pattern of common usage could be a sign that the meaning of *"existential"* is currently in flux, and evolving. Or, it could just be poor usage, at some level intended to make the user sound educated or intelligent. Or it could be I've just never recognized the possible uses available for *"existential"*.

https://wikidiff.com/realism/existential

https://wikidiff.com/existing/existential

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/existential

Comment: *Existential* can certainly be concrete: "Global warming is an existential threat to humanity" ([paraphrasing slightly](https://news.un.org/en/story/2018/05/1009782)), which does not mean the same as "Global warming is an existing threat". I'm not sure why you're citing wikidiff and vocabulary.com rather than proper dictionaries edited by experienced lexicographers: Merriam-Webster and Lexico both have detailed definitions with multiple meanings. If any sense of *existential* is misused, it's probably the philosophical one!

Comment: Your example is precisely the kind of use that sounds to me like a misuse. In the case of your example, the meaning is precisely the same as "existing" or "current" - there isn't any difference. Although, if you can tell me how they differ, I'm listening. I used the links because they were convenient and to the point. I will say this, 20 years ago, perhaps even only 10 years ago, I do not believe you would find many examples of "existential" in use in the concrete fashion of your example. Which was my point.

Comment: @StuartF, you want Merriam-Webster, no problem. AFAIC, it strongly supports my belief that the current fashion of usage, as in your example, is a misuse (esp. compared to usage in the 20th century). Look at the examples provided on M-W. Each has to do with a philosophical examination of objective and empirical reality. OTOH, usage such as you have quoted ("existential threat") relies on, I believe M-W's def 2.b.:*"having being in time and space"*. While this is reasonable, it ignores the history of usage,   (1 of 2)

Comment: @StuartF (2 of 2),  and words such as "current", "existing", "empirical" could easily be substituted, without changing the meaning, and would likely be more readily understood by the average audience.  I still think the current usage fashion is an evolution of usage - a change - from past usage.

Comment: Yes, I find some examples of "existential", "... another sign of NATO's existential crisis", "Climate summit tackles 'existential crisis'."